# Can every bounded function on an interval be "integrated"?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

There are of course various and increasingly general notions of integrability, including some notions on the real line that I'm told properly generalize Lebesgue integration in that context.  Is one known to be the "most general" in a meaningful sense?

To make this question far more concrete, let
$$B_c(\mathbb{R}) := \left\{ f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \mid \text{$f$ is bounded,  $\operatorname{supp}f$ is compact} \right\}$$
Is it known whether there exists a linear function
$$\mathcal{I}:B_c(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$$
such that:

1. $\mathcal{I}f = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \, dx$ whenever $f$ is (say) Riemann integrable, and
2. The (say) dominated convergence theorem holds for $\mathcal{I}$,

perhaps after replacing "Riemann" with some other integral or "Dominated Convergence Theorem" with some other similar result?

Is the answer to any such question known?